# How to Import Excel 2007 file using SSIS - (Only SQL server 2005 installed)

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, ssis

Hi In my production servers i have only excel 2003 and SQL server 2005 installed I have excel 2007 files to be imported is there a way to do this installing service pack, new driver etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that SSIS uses an internal Excel import/export methodology (i.e. it is possible to import using excel source in a package even if you do not have excel installed on the server).  Most places I have worked do not allow office apps to be installed on servers.  That being said, you should be able to import from most any version of excel with SSIS 2005.  You may need to go up to SQL 2008 for Excel 2010, but I am not sure on that.